# Take a google map using ajax by php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, google-maps

I am traying to show a google map in my main page. This map is generated by this function:

```
function addressCode(id,concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa) {
                var geocoder;
                var map;
                    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-35.397, -60.644);
                    var mapOptions = {
                        zoom: 5,
                        center: latlng
                    }
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(id), mapOptions);

                    var address = concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa;
                    geocoder.geocode( {
                        'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map,
                                position: results[0].geometry.location
                            });
                        } else {
                            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                        }
                    }); 
                    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',addressCode);  
                }
```

This function is defined in the main page. Then using ajax, I call the php file `take_publications`, in this file I print the following code:

```
$comillas='"' ;
    echo " <div id='$mapa'";
    echo "onload='addressCode('$mapa','$concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa')' style='position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;'> </div>";
    echo "<script >addressCode('$mapa','$concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa');";
    echo "setInterval(";
    echo $comillas."addressCode('$mapa','$concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa')".$comillas;
    echo ", 10000 );
         </script >";
```

`$mapa` is a string with the `id` of the tag, this variable is used as argument in the function `addressCode`. `$concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa` is the address to use as argument in the function `addressCode`.

The problem is that the map is not loading, or rather, the script printed from the php file by ajax is not being executed.

Any idea what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a `div` element doesn't have `onload` events.

If you really want your script to be executed on load, add your call of `addressCode` in a `window.onload` event handler, like this :

```
window.onload = function(){
    //do anything here
};
```

Then, concerning the use of `setInterval`, if you don't need IE < 10 users to see your website, you can do :

```
setInterval(addressCode, 1000, "#yourmap", "nohablospanishenoughtounderstandthat");
```

Otherwise, you should do :

```
setInterval(function(){ addressCode("#yourmap","blabla"); }, 1000);
```

(Note that I don't support the use of `setInterval`, you better use `setTimeout`)

Finally, stop using the register_globals helper. It will never help you. Like never ever.

```
"<div id='$mapa'"
```

Should be :

```
"div id='".$mapa."'"
```

So after all, your code should look like this :

```
echo "<div id='".$mapa."'";
echo "style='position:relative; width:400px; height:400px;'></div>";
echo "<script>";
echo "window.onload = function(){ ";
echo "addressCode('".$mapa."','".$concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa."');";
echo "setInterval(";
echo "addressCode, 1000, '".$mapa."','".$concatenadoAMostrarEnMapa."'";
echo ");";
echo "};";
echo "</script >";
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanations! i will apply it, i am new in web page development.
I tried to use your code, but it doesn't worl :/

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the exact answer but you can use this code for ur website..

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(24.376202, 92.163641),
          zoom: 18,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: change the latitude and longitude as per ur choise

Comment: This code is useful if you have only one map to show, however i have a list of maps to show.

Comment: I have one doubt- ur lat/long will be diff or same for every call ?

Comment: Same call, differents parameters

Answer (score 0):

After have been searching all night, I found the solution. I had to evaluate all scritps brought by ajax, because i was inserting new scritps but the page had already loaded all its content.

Thanks!